# How to use different loss function in tensorflow, DNNLinearCombinedClassifier

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using google tensorflow [TensorFlow Wide & Deep Learning](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide_and_deep/) to predict CTR.
The code was based on [wide_n_deep_tutorial.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py).

However, the auc is bad. I checked the code and found that, int the DNN_Linear_Combined.py, the loss function was defined as

```
loss = math_ops.reduce_mean(loss_unweighted, name=name)
```

In CTR prediction, train data was imbalanced. So if this kind of loss function is used, the loss will be better when predict more samples in negtive class(majority class).

What's more, the CTR predicted is much bigger than true CTR. (The true CTR is less than 1%, the mean predicted CTR is about 30%.)

My question is: how to modify the code to use logloss? Does the TF provide this?
I checked the code and found the following:

1. function `math_ops.reduce_logsumexp` in tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py
2. function `_log_loss_with_two_classes` in tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/head.py

However, the first does not make change with the `math_ops.reduce_sum`. And I don't know how to use the second function.

In a word, my question can be summarized as: how to modify the code to use the logloss function.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the task that are you training to solve? What is your dataset? Please clarify those aspects.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to calculate the logloss, and loss is given then you can calculate logloss as below and you don't need to change the code:

```
log_loss = math_ops.log(loss)
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you give more detail? My purpose is not to calculate the logloss, but to train the model with logloss function as object function. In estimator/head.py, `loss, weighted_average_loss = _loss( parametors)`. So which function should i use to get the logloss? Thanks.